# C# can cast LINQ Aggregate to double to output factorial, this works for integer up to 12

Tags: c#, casting, range, aggregate, enumerable

I want to fill the list with factorials using linq.
I got this, this works up to 12. I assume it's because of the integer range. But I couldn't retype it to double. Can this be easily modified (retyped)?

```
var listOfFactorials = from fact in Enumerable.Range(0, 171).Reverse().ToList() select new { Number = fact, Factorial = (fact == 0) ? 1d : Enumerable.Range(1, fact).Aggregate((i, j) => (i * j))};
```

I want to have the list filled with factorials up to the number 170.
I don't need it for anything, just playing for fun :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use BigInteger:

```
var listOfFactorials = from fact in Enumerable.Range(0, 200).Reverse().ToList()
                        select new 
                        { 
                            Number = fact, 
                            Factorial = (fact == 0) ? BigInteger.One : Enumerable.Range(1, fact)
                                                                                 .Select( i => new BigInteger(i))
                                                                                 .Aggregate((i, j) => (i * j))
                        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `double` - it only gives you 15 digits of precision in exchange for the larger range. You want to use either `long` or `BigInteger`.

You can either convert the integers returned from `Range` before calling `Aggregate`:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, fact)
          .Select(i => new BigInteger(i))
          .Aggregate((i, j) => (i * j))};
```

or use the more verbose version of `Aggregate` where you specify the types separately:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, fact)
          .Aggregate<int, BigInteger>(new BigInteger(1), (i, j) => (i * j))
```

Note that Long will overflow at `67!` while `BigInteger` is unbounded in theory

Answer (score 0):

Note that your `Aggregate` is not very efficient since it recalculates from 1 to n every time, if you start with 1, you can just do one multiple for each subsequent value:

```
var listOfFactorials = Enumerable.Range(1, 170)
                                 .Aggregate(new[] { new { Number = 0, Factorial = BigInteger.One } }.ToList(),
                                            (ans, n) => { ans.Add(new { Number = n, Factorial = ans.Last().Factorial * n }); return ans; })
                                 .AsEnumerable()
                                 .Reverse();
```

Since the sequence is initialized with the `0` value, the range must start at `1` for one fewer values.

A simpler (and probably more understandable) method would be to just use a `for` loop:

```
var ans = new[] { new { Number = 0, Factorial = BigInteger.One } }.ToList();
var Factorial = BigInteger.One;
for (int Number = 1; Number < 171; ++Number) {
    Factorial *= Number;
    ans.Add(new { Number, Factorial });
}
ans.Reverse();
```

Comment: Thank you all very much for your reply.
I finally got it, thanks to you. How I messed up. You taught me a lot.

You're right, I didn't think of it that way. But your code doesn't work for me. And I can't remove the error. I still have a lot to learn. It gives me errors CS0266 and CS1662 (in .NET 6.0)

Comment: @SpRosťa Ah, my fault. That is because I am using an extension method `Append` for `List` that isn't in .Net by default. I modified the answer to use built-in methods only.